# Property 'removeChild' does not exist on type 'NodeListOf<Element>'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, dom

I am trying to remove all the elements containing a className but I am not getting "Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'NodeListOf'." error .

```
 const questionKey = SelectElement.getAttribute("data-key").value;
const currentQuestionId = SelectElement.getAttribute("data-current-question").value;
const questionData = getCategoryQuestionsByProfile?.data?.questionOptionsList.filter(
  (d) => Number(hierarchyQuestionId) === Number(d.id)
);
const bqCounter = document.querySelectorAll(".bq-counter");
// for (let index = 0; index < bqCounter.length; index++) {
//   if (index + 1 > questionLevel) {
//     let elem = document.querySelectorAll(".bq_detect_" + questionKey + "_" + (index + 1));
//     elem.remove();
//   }
// }
bqCounter.forEach((e, index){
  if (index + 1 > questionLevel) {
    let elem = document.querySelectorAll(".bq_detect_" + questionKey + "_" + (index + 1));
    elem.remove();
  }
} )
```

Comment: remove() and removeChild() both doesn't exist

Comment: I have used "dom.iterable" in tsconfig but still it gives me error

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll is returning a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), in order to delete all elements of this list you should iterate and remove element, for example :

```
const elems = document.querySelectorAll(".bq_detect_" + questionKey + "_" + (index + 1));

for (const elem of elems) {
    elem.remove();
}
```

If there is only one element with this classname, you can simply use :

```
const elem = document.querySelector(".bq_detect_" + questionKey + "_" + (index + 1));
elem.remove();
```

Comment: I am trying to get all the elements of with that className as you can see, so can you suggest what can we use instead of doing it this way....

Comment: I don't understand what you want to get, is there only one element with the classname : ".bq_detect_" + questionKey + "_" + (index + 1) ?